# How can subscribe json.store when it updates?

Tags: android, python, json, kivy

I have an kivy app runing in ubuntu and android, this app ask some values, this values are stored in `json.store`. But if it's already had other values in this `json.store`, this values are going to be accumulate. This way, if I have stored `5` and I place `10`, I am going to have `510`. My json funcion to save values is:

```
store.put('carro', velocidade=carro0, tempo=carro1)
```

where `carro0` and `carro1` are entries. I would like to subscribe the `json.store` every time I get new entries. I didn't show my code here, because the only "pure python" of the app is this line. Very thanks everybody, and sorry if I had some english mistakes.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, because the problem was only the wrong way that I was "showing" in kivy display. I was doing:

```
car.ids.a0.text += store.get('tempo0')['velocidade']
```

rather than:

```
car.ids.a0.text = store.get('tempo0')['velocidade']
```

where `car` is the respective `screen`, `a0` is the `TextInput` id. I am sorry for this unnecessary post.